# Frobenius Condition for a specific first order pde

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

I would appreciate it if Someone would be kind enough to share some insights about the following question:

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a 3 dimensional Riemannian manifold. Consider the following system of pdes:
 $<\nabla^g \phi_1 , \nabla^g u>_g =0$   and $ <\nabla^g \phi_2 , \nabla^g u>_g=0$

Geometrically this is equivalent to trying to find a function whose level sets are perpendicular to level sets of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$.

Can this always be done at least locally? Is the Frobenius integrability condition satisfied?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Set $V$ to be the subbundle of $TM$ whose fiber at $p$ is the span of $\nabla\phi_1(p)$ and $\nabla\phi_2(p)$. Your equation on $u$ is equivalent to requiring that $du$ vanishes on $V$. Frobenius integrability theorem tells you it has (**EDIT:** non constant) local solutions if and only if $V$ is integrable (i.e. it is stable under Lie bracket). It is not too hard to find functions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ such that $[\nabla\phi_1(p),\nabla\phi_2(p)]\notin V$.

> **EDIT:** This example is actually false, the one provided by Deane Yang works.
>     <s>For instance on $\mathbb{R}^3$, take $\phi_1(x,y,z)=x$ and $\phi_2(x,y,z)=xyz$.</s>

Comment: I am not sure what I am missing here...I agree with the condition you have mentioned but I am not sure the example works.. to make this clear take $ u(x_1,x_2,x_3) = e^{\frac{x_3^2-x_2^2}{2}}$

Comment: It is clear that u solves the aforementioned system of odes in the question in euclidean space

Comment: I'll have a look but I'm skeptical.

Comment: Ok, I did the computation: if $u$ solves the problem, so does any $f(u)$ for $f$ a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. So I'll take $u(x,y,z)=z^2-y^2$ instead of yours. Then $\nabla\phi_1=\partial_x$ and $\nabla\phi_2=yz\partial_x+xz\partial_y+xy\partial_z$, while $\nabla u= 2z\partial_z-2y\partial_y$. On can check that the inner products between the gradients don't vanish everywhere.

Comment: :your example simply does not work as one can clearly see that the inner products DO vanish everywhere actually as I also mentioned above. Anyways one can indeed find many examples where the system has no solution. Thanks for your comment

Comment: My bad. This case is integrable actually.

Answer (score 2):

In any dimension it appears to me that what happens depends on the smallest "Lie algebra" that contains the two vector fields $V = \nabla\phi_1$ and $W = \nabla\phi_2$. If the iterated Lie brackets of $V$ and $W$ generate a sub-bundle (i.e, the rank of the subspace at each point is a constant independent of the point), then that sub-bundle is integrable. Then $u$ most be constant along the integral submanifolds.

ADDED: In dimension 3 there are only two nonsingular possibilities: Either $[V,W]$ always lies in the span of $V$ and $W$ or $[V,W]$ sis always transverse to the $2$-plane spanned by $V$ and $W$. In the first case, the span of $V$ and $W$ is integrable and $u$ can be any function that is constant along the integral surfaces. In the latter, $u$ must be constant on the whole manifold.

Other cases are more difficult to analyze.

Comment: I see. That means in dimension 3, such a u always exists locally though right?

Comment: Oh I guess such a u might not exist in the singular cases

Comment: Yes, in the sense that the constant function always satisfies those two equations. As Thomas Richard said, a nonconstant solution exists only if the Frobenius condision holds. This is not necessarily so.

Comment: My bad. Of course the constant solution is not interesring. Thanks

Comment: An example where Frobenius does not hold is: $$\phi_1 = x + z \text{ and }\phi_2 = y + z^2$$