# Isothermal-related functions in higher dimensions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

I am interested in getting some geometrical or analytical perspective in studing the following complex pde. I would appreciate any help.

Consider $ (M,g)$ to be a 3 dimensional Riemannian manifold and consider solving the following pde near a surface $\Sigma$

$<d\Phi,d\Phi>_g =0$ where $\Phi$ is a complex valued function.

If the dimenion is 2 then any function of $z=x_1 + i x_2$ would do the job in isothermal coordinates.

I understand the question is a bit vague but I am interested in general observations about solvability of this pde.
Thanks,

Comment: Isothermal coordinates exist locally iff the manifold is conformally flat. This always happens in dimension two. In 3D this is equivalent with vanishing Cotton tensor and in higher dimensions Weyl tensor. That is, in general isothermal coordinates don't exist in higher dimensions.

Comment: you are completely right but this question is not necessarily asking to find isothermal coordinates in a 3-d manifold. I just put the word isothermal coordinates because in 2-d, solutions to the pde are related to isothermal coordinates. I have edited the title

Comment: I know the question is not about isothermal coordinates per se, but it sounded like you would have liked to have isothermal coordinates in higher dimensions as well.

Answer (score 5):

In the analytic category, there is a (local) existence theorem, but I don't know about the smooth category.  (I rather suspect that there might be some obstructions in the smooth case.)  Here is what you can say in the analytic case (and this works in all dimensions):

Suppose that $(M^n,g)$ is a real-analytic Riemannian manifold and that $\Sigma\subset M$ is an embedded real-analytic hypersurface with a choice of normal unit vector field $N$ along $\Sigma$.  Denote the induced metric on $\Sigma$ by $\bar g$.  Suppose that $f:\Sigma\to \mathbb{C}$ is a real-analytic function that satisfies $\langle \mathrm{d}f,\mathrm{d}f\rangle_{\bar g}= -h^2$ where $h:\Sigma\to\mathbb{C}$ is nonvanishing.  Then there exists an open $\Sigma$-neighborhood $U\subset M$ and a function $\Phi:U\to\mathbb{C}$ that satisfies the differential equation $\langle \mathrm{d}\Phi,\mathrm{d}\Phi\rangle_{g}= 0$
and the initial conditions $\mathrm{d}\Phi(N) = h$ and $\Phi = f$ along $\Sigma$.  Moreover, the solution is unique in the sense that any other solution $\Phi':U'\to\mathbb{C}$ of the differential equation with these initial conditions that is real-analytic satisfies $\Phi=\Phi'$ on some open $\Sigma$-neighborhood $U''\subset U\cap U'$.

All of this follows as a direct application of the Cartan-Kähler Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution for $2$ dimensions works for any dimension. You simply solve for co-ordinates $x^1, \dots, x^n$ such that the metric tensor $g_{ij}dx^idx^j$ satisfies
$$
g_{11} = g_{22},\ g_{12} = 0
$$
and set $f = x^1$, $g = x^2$. This is effectively parameterized isothermal co-ordinates, so your title is justified. You should be able to get solutions near a point by fixing a foliation of $2$-dimensional surfaces and solving for isothermal co-ordinates along each surface in such a way that the solution depends smoothly on the other $n-2$ co-ordinates.

ADDED: Here's a more explicit description in dimension 3: Start with co-ordinates $y^1$, $y^2$, and $y^3$ (where the level sets of $y^3$ give the foliation.) and a metric $g = g_{ij}dy^idy^j$. We want to solve for functions $\phi^1$ and $\phi^2$ such that if
$$
y^1 = \phi^1(x^1,x^2,x^3),\ y^2 = \phi^2(x^1,x^2,x^3),\ y^3 = x^3
$$
then the metric written with respect to $x^1, x^2, x^3$, $g = \hat{g}_{ij}dx^idx^j$ satisfies
$$
\hat{g}_{11} = \hat{g}_{22} \text{ and }\hat{g}_{12} = 0.
$$
A straightforward calculation shows that this is equivalent to
$$
g_{ab}\partial_1\phi^a\partial_1\phi^b = g_{ab}\partial_1\phi^a\partial_1\phi^b\text{ and }
g_{ab}\partial_1\phi^a\partial_2\phi^b = 0,
$$
where we sum over $1 \le a, b \le 2$. This is the same system of PDE's corresponding to finding co-ordinates $x^1, x^2, x^3$ such that $x^1, x^2$ are isothermal co-ordinates on any level set of $x^3$. In particular, since it involves only differentiation in the $x^1$ and $x^2$ directions and is elliptic, it can be solved for each value of the "parameter" $x^3$ using the standard approach for constructing isothermal co-ordinates. You can then verify that $\Phi = dx^1 + i dx^2$ satisfies $\langle d\Phi,d\Phi\rangle_g = 0$.

CORRECTION: Robert Bryant points out that the wrong problem is being solved above. The correct PDE is
$$
0 = \langle\partial\Phi,\partial\Phi\rangle_g = g^{ij}\partial_i\Phi\partial_j\Phi.
$$
Since $\Phi$ is complex-valued, this consists of 2 real equations for two real-valued functions. The linearization can be shown to be elliptic, if $\partial\Phi$ has maximal rank. Therefore, local solutions exist. However, the construction above of isothermal co-ordinates on each leaf of a foliation does not work.

CORRECTION to the CORRECTION: The linearized system is not elliptic. It is, however, generically <strike>hypoelliptic</strike> subelliptic. Given this, I believe that local solutions exist, but the only way I can see how to prove this is by proving smooth tame estimates for a solution to the <strike>hypoelliptic</strike> subelliptic PDE and using the Nash-Moser implicit function theorem.

Comment: Thanks you for your response. Suppose as per your suggestion I pick a foliation of 2-dimensional surfaces $\Sigma_t$ and I pick $\Phi|_{\Sigma_0}$ to be isothermal coordinates on $\Sigma_0$. Then it is clear to see that we would have $\partial_\nu \Phi = 0$ where $\nu$ is the unit normal to the surface and that would ofcourse be problematic. so I am thinking you do need the condition that Robert mentioned in his response, i.e that h be non vanishing

Comment: Why is $\partial_\nu\Phi = 0$?

Comment: Well we have $ <d\Phi,d\Phi>_g = (\partial_{\nu} \Phi)^2 +  <d\Phi,d\Phi>_{g^0}$ where $g^0$ is the induced metric on the surface...

Comment: No, the equation $\partial_\nu\Phi = 0$ does not necessarily hold, because it implies that the co-ordinates $x^1$ and $x^2$ are invariant under the flow induced by the normal vector (in dimension 3). This however does not necessarily hold for the almost-isothermal co-ordinates.

Comment: What I am saying is precisely this: let $\Sigma_0$ be an embedded surface in M and suppose you are trying to find $\Phi$ subject to the constraint that $<d\Phi,d\Phi>_{g0}=0$  This is simply impossible

Comment: There's no constraint in $g$ or $g_0$. Restricting to dimension $3$, I'm starting with a single co-ordinate function $x^3$ and solving for two more co-ordinate functions $x^1$ and $x^2$ such that $\partial_1\cdot\partial_1 = \partial_2\cdot\partial_2$ and $\partial_1\cdot\partial_2 = 0$.

Comment: Deane, I think that there is a misunderstanding. The equations that say that $\Phi= x^1+i\,x^2$ satisfies $\langle\mathrm{d}\Phi,\mathrm{d}\Phi\rangle_g=0$ are *not* $g_{11}-g_{22}=g_{12}=0$.  They are $g^{11}-g^{22}=g^{12}=0$.  The former are two equations on the entire coordinate system, while the latter are two equations on the two functions $x^1$ and $x^2$, so they are different if $n>2$.  In fact, if $\Phi = u + i\,v$, then  $$0=\langle\mathrm{d}\Phi,\mathrm{d}\Phi\rangle_g= g(\nabla\Phi,\nabla\Phi) = \bigl(g(\nabla u,\nabla u){-}g(\nabla v,\nabla v)\bigr) + 2i\, g(\nabla u,\nabla v).$$

Comment: Robert, thanks! Will have to rethink this.

Comment: @DeaneYang:  I agree with your comments above about the hypoelliptic nature of the problem.  However, I think that, at least in higher dimensions, the smooth tame estimates might be hard to come by because the linearization of the problem at a solution $\Phi = u+ i\,v$ will be hypoelliptic only if the $2$-plane field spanned by $\nabla u$ and $\nabla v$ is bracket-generating.  This is generic in all dimensions, as you say, but as the dimension $n$ increases, it's higher and higher order and thus, presumably, more difficult to analyze.  When $n=3$, though, it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: The correct terminology might be "subelliptic" rather than "hypoelliptic". The operator also reminds me of the $\bar\partial_b$ operator on a generic CR-manifold. Perhaps that theory could provide some useful guidance on how to prove local existence. Checking Google, I also see that there has been a fair amount of work on nonlinear subelliptic PDE's.

Comment: Thanks to both for insightful comments! @Robert Bryant Could I ask you to share an insight on this topic as well? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/188244/frobenius-condition-for-a-specific-first-order-pde

Comment: The reason I ask this, is that it has some level of similarity to the question at hand here.

Comment: @Ali:  I had a look at the other question, but I don't understand what you would like me to do.  The answers given there are correct:  For most pairs of functions $(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ on $(M^3,g)$ the Lie bracket of their gradient vector fields will be linearly independent from those gradients, in which case, there is no nonconstant solution $u$ to the problem, just as they wrote (and for the reasons they stated).  Is there something else you wanted to know?

Comment: @DeaneYang:  Well, I agree that the problem is always subelliptic, but it's also clear that the linearization of the equation at a *generic* solution really is hypoelliptic (because the $2$-plane field spanned by $\nabla u$ and $\nabla v$ will be bracket-generating).  It's curious because, while there apparently can be nonanalytic solutions (even when the metric is real-analytic), it seems (when the metric is real-analytic) that the *generic* solution  must be real-analytic.

Comment: Robert, thanks for the clarification. I misremembered the difference between hypoelliptic and subelliptic and mistakenly thought hypoelliptic was a stronger condition. And I've completely forgotten (assuming I once knew) the subtleties of such operators when the coefficients are real-analytic. How can the generic solution be real-analytic and yet non-real-analytic solutions exist?

Comment: @Robert Bryant: no Robert, their answers are perfectly valid and correct thanks for your time